# PHP - Joomla 3 site-defines.php disappear after some time

Tags: php, joomla

I am getting this message on my site, PHP Warning:

> require_once() [function.require-once]: Unable to access /home/sddalmac/public_html/includes/defines.php in /home/sddalmac/public_html/index.php on line 28

After I restore defines.php file, site works fine for few hours and then file disappear again. Same is for user and for admin interface.
Server PHP version is: 5.3.29

Does anyone knows solution for this problem?

Comment: Please check your server logs as there could be a script deleting this file. Might also be worth contacting your hosting company

Comment: As above, I have noticed this happen on hacked websites. Upon improving them the next day they files can be deleted. Firstly contact your host to see if they are having issues which means they are doing restores(I hope they are not!). Failing that, do a full audit of your website.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, website is hacked. PHP exploit.
Reason: Known exploit = [Fingerprint Match] [PHP DarkLeech Exploit [P0990]]

Thanks to all.